# Google Maps connect points with lines

Tags: google-maps

I cant find any useful answer for my questions. I exported points from kml. now i must connect this point with line on google maps api v3. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (gLine is a global var, gTheMap is the Google map object);

```
   // draw a line connecting the points
    var Endpoints = [marker1.position, marker2.position];

    if (gLine == null)
    {
        gLine = new google.maps.Polyline(
            {   path: Endpoints,
                strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                map: gTheMap
            });
    }
    else
       gLine.setPath(Endpoints);
```

I blogged about this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2012/12/09/google-and-bing-map-apis-compared.aspx).

Comment: thanks for answer.. But if i i have over 100 points does it work?

Comment: Put all your points in this array: var Endpoints = [marker1.position, marker2.position,...more points];